# Javascript - innerHTML returns undefined then results

Tags: javascript, undefined, innerhtml

```
<head>
<script>
function whammo()
{
    var i = 1;
    while(i<=5)
    {
        document.write("<h6>Test</h6>");
        i=i+1;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='page'></div>
<script>
document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = whammo();
</script>

</body>
```

The whammo function is to return 5 h6 Tests to be displayed, but it returns the following:
undefined
Test
Test
Test
Test
Test

I did my testing here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_elmnt_innerhtml

Why is undefined being returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a string, and return the value from `whammo`

```
function whammo()
{
    var i = 1, html = '';
    while(i<=5)
    {
        html  += "<h6>Test</h6>";
        i=i+1;
    }
    return html
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NKA7M/)

Comment: You're right, I suppose it tried to print the function return. So obvious now. Thank you for your help.
I wish I had more rep so I could upvote you.

Answer (score 1):

this one is shorter (and **Arun P Johny** forgot semicolon in the end)

```
function whammo() {
    for (var i=0, html=''; i<=5; i++) {
        html += '<h6>Test</h6>';
    }
    return html;
}
```

also, a piece of advise, use jsfiddle to show your own examples: http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/y2vbk/
instead of w3school

Comment: ArunPJohny was using the OP's code as much as possible in order to highlight the actual change they were making. Refactoring the entire function obscures what was fixed. The semicolon is recommended, but not *strictly* required.

Comment: You also ended up with an extra pass through the loop.

Comment: 1. you are right, I saw extra loop comparing my and ArunPJohny's fiddles but decided to leave as is, because the topicstarter tries to insert "test" multiple times, not exactly 5 times (also I'm a lil bit lazy, sorry), so I didn't think it's really important 2. I always try to follow recommendations, i think it's a good practice